# Recover Git local repository associated with Git private remote repository

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I am a contributor of one of the github private repository. I first cloned all the files (JAVA spring boot project) of remote repository and I made some changes of the code and added some new files. I used Intellij IDEA to open the project and make some changes. But I forgot to push my code or make any commit at that time.

The account holder who created the private repository just said that he had renamed the repository name. And now all my files are lost, I don't even see the folder where I cloned that repository. I had done lots of work on that project. I can't even see that folder in my recyle bin.

Is there any way to recover those files with the changes that I have made?
Please help!

Comment: i don't think there is a way for it if you already update your code from repository and lost your changes from your local. you can run "status" command to see if there is anything you have changed from the code or it is just same code with the repository.

Comment: try local history: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html

Comment: @PetrRastegaev it worked for me.. I created a new project with the same name as of the previous one and kept it on the same location. I then opened that project on Intellij and selected local history where i could find all the changes made on my previous project .Thanks it helped me alot.  I am now able to access all my previous code and changes .